# ChaCha20 IOS usage problems

Tags: java, ios, cryptography, libgdx, robovm

Stack: LibGDX, robovm, java(kotlin)
Platform: IOS
Algo: ChaCha
Task: encrypt/decrypt byte arrays

I've tried Cipher.getInstance(), but got NoSuchAlgorithmException on IOS (same code on Android build works fine). BC is visible among security providers.
I've tried bouncycastle's ChaChaEngine. Same result: Android - fine, IOS - ChaChaEngine class not found

Any ideas how to implement ChaCha on IOS or link to sourcecode to implement it by hands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue. Posting steps for anyone facing same problem:

1. Check your robovm.xml. It must contain not only basic concrete bouncy castle references but also `<pattern>com.android.org.bouncycastle.**</pattern>`
2. The problem is with this concrete algo. After step 1 you can move from ChaCha20 to AES/CFB/PKCS7Padding